# Character Count in Apex Code

Tags: apex

Is there any Apex exchange tool or utility which can give me the following details in an Apex class.

1. Number of methods defined
2. Number of SOQL's used

and the respective character count for each of those.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot tell about SOQL and the character count, but you can use the Tooling API to fetch data from `ApexClass`. There you get the `SymbolTable` object that contains list of all the methods used. Refer [Tooling API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf)

Another method is as @Enry suggested, by querying the `ApexClass` object and writing a parser of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I m not aware of packages to do that.

Some input to start from scratch:
You can query "Apex Class" object.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm

Query the body and then parse it as a string. For example you can count the number of "from" to know how many queries there are.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the case in here or not. But if there's a variable named fromAddress or fromLocation or from* the count will fail.